# How to change brightness before logging in?

Tags: 14.04, boot, laptop, brightness

Whenever I boot, the brightness is set to full. I read [this](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-12-04-laptop) and make changes so that it do not reset every time I boot into my laptop.

But before this, I tried to change brightness before login, but brightness buttons only work when I log in. So after my problem of **[Brightness is reset to Maximum on every Restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151651/brightness-is-reset-to-maximum-on-every-restart)** is solved, I just want to know any way to change the brightness just after OS start, that is before login.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/829814/295286  In particular , step 3 of my answer is the most relevant.  While slightly different in context, it does ask setting the login screen brightness. Let me know if everything is clear there. If so desired, I can post alternative answer.

Comment: This `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file is empty. Is it strange or normal?

Comment: Normal. If it was not edites before, it will be.empty

Comment: May your question be closed as a duplicate then ?

Comment: yeah maybe you are right, but what I think, it would be better if someone come to this question after google it, so he got a  direct solution here rather than going to **step 3** of [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/829814/295286). It would be difficult for anyone this.

Comment: OK. I could write an answer then. Also closed posts are searchable through google - they dont disappear

Comment: Yeah, but it will contribute in banning my account from asking more questions as (I don't know why) my questions never get upvotes, and closing of my questions will increase chances of ban me. So, it would be great for me to not to close this question and answer here, it would be good for other visitors too.  :)

Comment: OK, answer posted, let me know if everything is clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54474/discussion-between-siraj-and-serg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Running a script before or once login screen appears

There are two ways to approach this:

1. Place command or call to script in `/etc/rc.local`. For instance

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e
   #
   # rc.local
   #
   # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
   # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
   # value on error.
   #
   # In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
   # bits.
   #
   # By default this script does nothing.

   # path to my script. Note the & at the end, it's important
   /home/serg/bin/brightness_set.sh &
   exit 0
   ```
2. The login screen is actually known as desktop manager, and Ubuntu in particular uses `lightdm` desktop manager. Its configuration file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` can take `greeter-setup-script=` parameter to execute something before login screen actually shows up. For instance, you could do:

   ```
   [Seat:*]
   greeter-setup-script=/opt/set_brightness.py
   ```

   NOTE: Older versions of the header `[SeatDefaults]` is deprecated now, use `[Seat:*]`. Also, if  you have never edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` it will be blank - that's the normal behavior since 14.04 Ubuntu version.

#### Controlling the brightness:

Setting brightness will have to be done by writing to `brightness` file in  `/sys/class/backlight/<NAME>` directory. There are couple different `<NAME>` versions than can appear, for example mine is `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` , so you will need to figure out the name your own computer uses or alternatively use `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness`. There is also `max_brightness` file in the same location, which you can use as 100% value to calculate brightness to set. Both files accept integer value.

Common way to write into that file is via `echo 123 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` from command line. If you are running a script via `/etc/rc.local` or via `greeter-setup-script=` parameter mentioned above, `sudo` is not necessary, as both method run scripts with root privillege ( which is also important to remember for security reasons, so ensure your script is accessible only to your user or root only )
.

There are also alternatives to writing into `/sys` , but not all of them are good. In my experience `xbacklight` doesn't work for Ubuntu users and `xrandr --output SCREEN_NAME --brightness INT` is only a software solution (i.e., it doesn't actually decrease power of the screen, only makes screen turn darker color).

#### Additional resources

- If you want more flexible control over brightness and set specific level based on time of day, [see my script on the related question here](https://askubuntu.com/a/831379/295286)
- [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) article contains plenty of information about backlight and ways to control it.