# Control Redshift WIth Local Time

Tags: 18.04, xfce, redshift

On my phone, I have my screen change it's colour temperature at a specific time of the day in the morning and the night using local time. I also have an option to turn on/off the night mode quickly. I'd like to imitate that behavior on RedShift.

I'd like to configure RedShift to follow the clock blindly and completely disregard both the latitude/longitude I'm in and my local sunrise/sunset times. How may I go about doing this?

Also, redshift-gtk seems to lack an icon to quickly toggle day/night mode. Is there an alternative UI, or must I do this via CLI?

I'm on UbuntuStudio 18.04 LTS (Xfce4 Desktop) BTW.

Comment: I created eyesome: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829814/set-initial-startup-background-brightness-depending-on-daytime/887249#887249 which you can override `sunrise` and `sunset` time variables. It has a GUI and controls three monitors independently for brightness (hardware or software) and color temperatures. Also I'm more than happy to update eyesome.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any good UIs for `redshift`.  I am only aware of good control via CLI.  As long as `redshift` is not running in the background controlling the temperatures you can do command line commands like:

```
redshift -O 3500 &
```

or whatever temp you want it to be set to.  Then to reset back do:

```
redshift -x
```

The reason you don't want `redshift` running in the background is as soon as you run the `-O` or `one shot mode` it will reset it back to whatever it is supposed to be at this time of either `DAY` or `NIGHT` within a few seconds.

You can look into adding these lines to a script or add the commands themselves to a `cron` job where you can set it to run at your own times.  I do recommend a script though that runs with a time check on it like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129042/2012250

Hope this helps!