# Unable to lower screen brightness when Night Light is ON

Tags: 19.04, screen, hp, brightness, xrandr

I installed Ubuntu 19.04 on an HP Spectre x360 with 4k Oled Display. Many issues I've encountered with the screen (such as not being able to tweak its screen brightness the usual way  and instead needing to set it via command line) but now I see that I'm not able to adjust the screen brightness while keeping Night Light turned ON.

What I do:

1. Turn on Night Light via GUI and it works.
2. Lower the screen brightness by running:

   ```
   xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.8
   ```
3. The brightness gets lowered and the color of the screen resets to default, even though Night Light still shows to be turned ON.
4. Get back to Night Light preferences, move the Color Temperature slider and Night Light gets back in command of my screen, changing its color hue but resetting its brightness to 100%.

I work really long hours with this machine, so I really need to be able to have both things working at the same time since this is taking a toll on my sight.

I hope someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I control this using the Gnome Extension Adjust Brightness Icon

[image]

This places a lightbulb icon on the top bar which, when you click on it adjusts the screen brightness in steps.

The cycle is 4 steps; the 4th step returning the screen to it's native state.

If you are not certain about installing Gnome Extensions Navigate your Firefox browser to https://extensions.gnome.org/ and simply search for Adjust Brightness Icon extension. Flip the ON switch to install the extension. Complete the installation of the extension by clicking on the ON switch then click Install to confirm.

Comment: Is it compatible with gnome night light?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS/gnome and set the night light on in settings.

Answer (score 1):

## Eyesome

If you can't solve the problem, I wrote a bash script called [eyesome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829814/set-initial-startup-background-brightness-depending-on-daytime/887249#887249) that lets you control brightness and color temperature (gamma) at the same time. Additional benefits:

- Define three monitors with different settings
- Override two monitors (blank on inactivity) when watching movie on a third TV
- Gradually increase in unnoticeable steps at dusk and dawn
- In use longer than Gnome Night Light (granted not as many users)

## Sample screen

[image: eyesome monitor 3.png]

Answer (score 0):

if you look in the app store you will find OLED Dimmer. It works with dell xps 15 7590 and Ubuntu 19.10. I would imagine it would work with your system too but cannot say for sure,

Comment: Does it coexist with Nightlight running at the same time?